# 'Function call' is an illegal expression for an augmented assignment in python

Tags: for-loop, random, variable-assignment

I'm practicing on a code which has...

```
totals = {4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0}

for _ in range(1000):
   decades = random.choice(4,5,6,7,8)
   totals(decades) += 1
```

The last line gives a syntax error mentioned above.

Comment: Do you mean `totals[decades] += 1`? (notice the `[ ]`)

Answer (score 1):

The code which you have provided has many invalid syntaxes here is your code after removing the errors:

```
import random

totals = {4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0}

for _ in range(1000):
   decades = random.choice((4,5,6,7,8))
   totals[decades] += 1
```

Now lets understand the error which you are getting

```
SyntaxError: 'function call' is an illegal expression for augmented assignment
```

This error you are getting at this line `totals(decades) += 1` here I am damn sure that you wanted to increment the value corresponding to a particular key inside of the totals dictionary the correct way to do that is `totals[decades] += 1`.

But still, why are you getting the `Syntax Error`? First, if we remove the assignment from `totals(decades) += 1` and simply write `print(totals(decades))` this will give an error

```
print(totals(decades))

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable.
```

Notice it is `Type Error` which is a runtime error that occurred during the program execution.

But the error you were getting was a `Syntax Error` because Python has banned augmented assignment to a temporary object so you cannot perform augmented operations on temporary objects whenever you use them it will throw a `Syntax Error`. This is a `Syntax Error`
means you are trying to `totals(decades) += 1` modify a temporary object.

## Demo

```
a = 50
def foo():
    return a

foo() += 1

foo() += 1
^
SyntaxError: 'function call' is an illegal expression for augmented assignment
```